# Superscript on top and subscript on bottom in equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, subscripts

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
u_{k}^{i} = \frac{\sqrt[k]{\Pi_{j=1}^{k}a_{ij}}}{\sum_{i=1}^{k}\sqrt[k]{\Pi_{j=1}^{k}a_{ij}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The result I get is this

[image]

what I want is this

[image]

somehow inside equation, the subscript & superscript positioned at the side not on top and bottom as I wanted them. How can I do that?

Comment: Try `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`.

Comment: I tried it and the result is still the same

Comment: Don't use `\Pi` to denote the product symbol. Instead, please use `\prod`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\sum\limits` instead of `\sum` and `\prod\limits` instead of `\Pi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
u_{k}^{i} = 
\frac
{\sqrt[k]{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}a_{ij}}}
{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\sqrt[k]{\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}a_{ij}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @hair-splitter . It worked perfectly